# Using :contains to find a particular td element

Tags: jquery

I have the following rendered html:

```
<table width="420" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Amount Due:</td>
<td>$168.88</td>
</tr>
```

My final goal is to obtain and change the value shown after Total Amount Due. I have started by trying to select the element containing the text "Total Amount Due:".

Here is my code attempting this:

```
var tdElement = $("td:contains('Total Amount Due:')");
alert($(tdElement).text());
```

I have tried changing the syntax a bit in the command line of Firebug, but when I do I always end up receiving an error in the first line. With the code like this, I do not receive an error until the second line where I get a TypeError: $(tdElement) is null.

Also, not sure if this affects anything but this table is actually within two other tables.

Comment: Give your significant elements proper classes and ids, then look for them. You can't rely on inner text, what if you go into `i18n` later?

Comment: Moreover, your problem lies elsewhere, as your markup/code works: http://jsfiddle.net/S73h7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get a TypeError: $(tdElement) is null.

Even if it doesn't match anything, jQuery returns a valid jQuery object (containing no matching elements), not `null`, so that sounds like either:

- You don't have jQuery loaded. Check the JavaScript console to see whether you have load errors and resolve any you find.
- Or you do have it loaded, but you also have another library like Prototype or MooTools loaded that has stolen the `$` symbol. If so, you have three choices (at least):

  1. Try to stop using the other library, and remove it from the page.
  2. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` everywhere you want to use jQuery.
  3. Or put your jQuery code in a function you can use to shadow the `$` symbol, like this:

     ```
     // If you have another library loaded, out here $ may not === jQuery
     (function($) {
         // Here, your code can happily assume $ === jQuery...
     })(jQuery);
     ```

Once you sort that out:

I'd strongly recommend not using `:contains` if the page is of any size. Instead, if that element is unique on the page, use an `id` and find it using `$("#theid")`. If not, use a class, and find it using `$(".theclass").find(":contains('Total Amount')")`.

And finally: You're using

```
var tdElement = $("td:contains('Total Amount Due:')");
```

but then also

```
alert($(tdElement).text());
```

There's no need to call `$` a second time, just use the first jQuery instance:

```
alert(tdElement.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

hey man give that td containing the amount e.g $320.00 a class or if you not want to give a class you need a psuedo.

Other thing that you have not specified the event on which you want to change with other value e.g on click of button change value i have done it with document ready function you can add any event to it and also the amount :)

CASE 1) IF YOU CAN GIVE CLASS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".amount").text("any value you want");
});

<table width="420" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>....</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Amount Due:</td>
            <td class="amount">$168.88</td>
        </tr>
```

CASE 2) YOU CANNOT ADD CLASS

I noticed that the `td` of which you want to change amount is children of tr which is last `tr` of `table`.So, We can use PSEUDO.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("table tbody tr:last td:last").text("any value you want");
});

<table width="420" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>....</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Amount Due:</td>
            <td>$168.88</td>
        </tr>
```

CASE 3) IF `TR` of table is second, third, fourth... in the case it is 3rd

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:last").text("any value you want");
});

<table width="420" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>....</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Amount Due:</td>
            <td>$168.88</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: man if above answer not solves your problem please inform me atleast by commenting!

Comment: This rather misses the point that jQuery won't return `null` regardless of the selector, so the reported error has nothing to do with `:contains` anyway...

Comment: sorry @T.J.Crowder can you explain your above comment in simple ENGLISH! English is my secondary language!

Comment: @ Aspiring: The OP said that he/she got the error `TypeError: $(tdElement) is null`. jQuery's `$` never returns `null`, even if nothing matched the selector you pass it. It returns an empty jQuery instance. So the selector is not the problem, the structure of the page is not the problem. The problem is probably a library conflict. See my answer for details.

Comment: oh yes, that's right man! that's my fault! I didn't even noticed that para :sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td', 'table').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('amount due') != -1;
}).next('td').text('$320.00');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J3q8C/)

Comment: It would be interesting to add a performance disclaimer to this answer.

Comment: @ adeneo: jQuery **already** provides a selector engine that supports `:contains`, no need to rewrite the functionality.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Mine is better !

Comment: @ adeneo: Uh huh. ;-) But this answer rather misses the point that jQuery won't return `null` regardless of the selector...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different configuration but I think it may work for you.

```
<table width="420" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Amount Due:</td>
<td id="amountDue">$168.88</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

​
and JavaScript:

```
alert($("td#amountDue").text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BAW8c/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to try and do something like the following?

```
<table width="420" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr><td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Amount Due:</td>
<td id="total-amount-due">$168.88</td>
</tr>
var ttl = $('#total-amount-due').text();
```

Seems that would be the easiest solution based on what you have posted.